How to grep the first string delimited by ''
How to grep the first string within '' in a text file?
in:
path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
path: 'registration',
path: 'employees',
path: 'recruitment',
path: 'work',

out:

login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

I tried:
grep -Po "path: '\K.*'" in


grep stands for g/re/p which are the ed commands to "Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result". Don't try to modify the text that matches before printing, it's not what grep is intended to do (Unix fundamentals:  every tool should do 1 thing and do it well) and so the result is non-portable at  best and there are other Unix tools intended for exactly that purpose, e.g. sed and awk,

@albertkao9 : do you actually want /login from 1st line ? or you want it to return an empty string ?

You might use gnu-awk with a regex and a capture group, capturing optional chars other than ' between 2 ' chars
awk 'match($0, /path: \047([^\047]*)\047/, a) {print a[1]}' file

Output
[empty line] <--
login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

If you are using grep -P for a Perl compatible regular expression with a negated character class [^']* and a lookahead , but that does not print the empty line:
grep -Po "path: '\K[^']*(?=')" file

Output
login
registration
employees
recruitment
work


Since standard grep doesn't give us an option to print a capture group, here is a sed solution that would capture text between pair of ' and print the capture group:
sed -E "s/path: '([^']*)'.*/\1/" file

login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

This doesn't require any gnu utils as this solution with any version of sed.

What about this:
grep "," file1.txt | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | sed -e "s|path: ||g" | sed -e "s|'||g"


grep "," : only show the lines with a comma
awk -F "," '{print $1}' : treat the comma as a separator and only show first column
sed -e "s|path: ||g" : remove the word "path:"
sed -e "s|'||g" : remove the single quotes


grep/sed/awk | grep/sed/awk is an antipattern, you can always do whatever that pipeline does using just awk or sometimes just sed. A literal translation of grep "," file1.txt | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | sed -e "s|path: ||g" | sed -e "s|'||g" into a single awk call would be  awk -F',' '/,/{$0=$1; gsub(/path: /,""); gsub(/\047/,""); print}' file1.txt but of course there are better ways to do it with just awk.

@EdMorton: calling it an antipattern is quite strongly formulated. I have a very basic understanding of grep, awk and sed and generally this is the way I use them: grep is the filter, awk is the column shower and sed the replacer :-)

I don't think antipattern is too strong a word, Useless Use of Grep and/or Sed is very much in the same vein as the more famous Useless Use of Cat (UUOC), e.g. see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep where this issue has been documented for about a quarter of a century and was well known long before that. Wouldn't it be better to get a better understanding of how to use the tools so you avoid unnecessary code, resources, execution time, complexity, etc.? Your choice of course.

Using any cut or awk:
$ cut -d\' -f2 file

login
registration
employees
recruitment
work


$ awk -F\' '{print $2}' file

login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

That assumes you don't have any lines with just a single ' and that none of your strings have newlines within them. If either of those can exist then add them to the sample input/output in your question.

echo "path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      path: 'registration',
      path: 'employees',
      path: 'recruitment',
      path: 'work'," |


awk '$0=$2?$2:$4?$4:$6' FS='\47'


/login
login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

With a REALLY ugly regex :

awk '$0=$2' FS='(^([^\47]*(\47\47)?[^\47]*)+)?\47' 

/login
login
registration
employees
recruitment
work

